# WP plugin install complain can't create directory: Directory Permission is set to 775

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, debian

I have a nginx installation on an AWS server with Debian 12, I have setup the server to run as nginx group and with nginx user.

However, when I tried to install plugin from the dashboard, it keeps complaining that it cannot create a directory under the wp plugin directory, which is `./wp-content/plugins`.

The directory has a permission set to 775, which the owner is `admin` and the group is `nginx`. I also tried setting the owner to be nginx but still doesn't work.

The directory has a permission set to 775, which the owner is `admin` and the group is `nginx`. I also tried setting the owner to be nginx but still doesn't work.

I have looked at the log files but they gave me no useful information.

Anyone has a clue of how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some logs to help us?

Comment: Why is there a folder being created? The plugin is uploaded in .zip format unless I'm missing something. Is it uploaded successfully and then and error ... agreed some more information would help solve this.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is be dead certain about what user owns that process, and make sure that path is owned by that user, with 744 permissions, an apply a `chown` and `chmod` recursively on that path. And double check everything. That's is the correct configuration. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that PHP-FPM is still running www-data as the user and later I discovered I need to create a separate user for php-fpm pool for security reasons, so I did that.

After that I simply changed the owner of the document root of the website to the newly created user and it just works like a magic.